# Why my Jquery code doesne't work. Am i properly connected to Html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please help i know this is a noob question but I stuck on this for several days.Thanks in Advance.
This is my Jquery when I open JS cosole it shows me error $ is not definded.
Why my Jquery code doesne't work. Am i properly connected to Html?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#container').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '+=10px'
       });
   });
   $('#container').mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '-=10px'
       }); 
   });
   $('#container').click(function() {
       $(this).toggle(1000);
   }); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project</title>


<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

<script src="dev.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>




</head>
<body>


<div id = "container">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you are executing jQuery code before the availability of jQuery library

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V8qMm/41/

Answer (score 5):

Since your script file uses jQuery, ti should be added after jQuery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel like an A*hole now for this dumb question.